# Deriving the expected value of a random variable via another random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $T = \{1,2,\ldots\}$ and $T_0 = \{0\} \cup T$ denote finite sets. Further let $X_t$ denote a random variable with PDF $f$. Let $x = (x_t)_{t \in T}$ denote a vector of realizations of $(X_t)_{t \in T}$. For a given realization $x$ and constant $c \geq 0$ let $Y$ denote a second random variable. A realization of $Y$ being the number of times whenever $x_t > c$, i.e. $y(x, c) = |\{t  \mid x_t > c\}| \in T_0$.

I'm pretty sure that the expected value of $Y$ for a given $c$ is given by the following formula
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(Y; c) = \sum_{t \in T}{\int_{c}^{\infty}f(X_t) \mathrm{d} X_t} = \sum_{t \in T}{\mathrm{Pr}(X_t > c)}. 
\end{align}

I would not know how to link those two random variables formally though. Can someone verify that the expression is correct.

Comment: You can write $Y=\sum_{t\in T}1_{(c,\infty)}(X_t)$ and apply linearity of expectation. BTW, is $T$ a finite set?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, $T$ is finite.